# Count views every time someone visit the page with firebase and Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-router-dom

I want to count view every time the user visits the page using react-router-dom and Firebase, I have this Code:

```js
//useHistory is the react-router-dom dependency 
const history = useHistory();

const handleClick = () => history.push('/post');

if(handleClick) {
  db.collection("posts").doc(postId).update({
    views: increment,
  })
}
```

Its works But its give an Infinite Loop I tried useEffect Like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if(handleClick) {
    db.collection("posts").doc(postId).update({
      views: increment,
    })
  }
}, [handleClick])
```

and it still gave the infinite increments, is there a way to count views without running in this type of problem?

Comment: I think you can just use an empty dependency array? So it will only increment on the mount of the page.

Comment: Thank you, It worked when I removed the dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

It's not clear how the first snippet creates a render loop, but it certainly isn't correct. Each render/rerender of the component reruns the function component body, which means each render `handleClick` is redeclared, and OFC the `if (handleClick)` condition will *always* be true (*since it was defined just above*) and the "posts" collection will be updated each time.

Indeed, in the second snippet the issue is very nearly the same, each render/rerender of the component redeclares the `handleClick` function and this is a new reference in the dependency array it triggers the `useEffect` callback.

## Solutions

Use a mounting (*empty dependency array*) `useEffect` to trigger the db collection update.

```
useEffect(() => {
  db.collection("posts")
    .doc(postId)
    .update({
      views: increment,
    });
}, []);
```

It's not clear where the `postId` and `increment` values comes from, but I assume somewhere previously in the component code you've accessed the same collection and retrieved an "initial" `views` value from the DB.